# How should I add an author subtitle under a chapter title?

Tags: latex

Had trouble knowing what exactly to Google, so I'll ask here.

I'm typesetting a series of annotations to papers.  Each chapter will be on a paper, so I'd like to put the paper authors right under the chapter names (the paper titles).

I can think of a hacky way of doing this, but I figured I'd ask the fine folks over at SO first for something more elegant / contribute to the knowledge base.

Comment: Unless and until the vote balance on http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12918/can-we-have-a-ruling-on-latex-on-stackoverflow changes LaTeX is *in*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use a package designed for things like conference proceedings, such as [this one](http://www.slac.stanford.edu/econf/editors/fulltext-template/instructions.html)?

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `substr` package in addition of `titlesec` (with `explicit` option) for create a semantic way of putting authors in titles.

Then, you can write your chapter on this way:

```
\chapter{About random things on Internet, and another
procrastination issues. Alice Marigold}
```

In this case the title and the author are separated for a ". " (You can use another separator if you use periods in one of your titles). Then you can modify the `\chapter` format with `titlesec`. With the `explicit` option you can access directly to the title content with `#1`. Then you can separate the title and the author with the commands `\BeforeSubString` and `\BehindSubString` of the `substr` package, respectively. They have two arguments: the separator token (in this case is ". ") and the string (the title. author).

For a simple example:

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{}{%
   \Huge \thechapter.
}{1cm}{%
   \LARGE \scshape \BeforeSubString{. }{#1}\\
   {\Large \itshape ---\BehindSubString{. }{#1}---}%
}
```

[The result is similar to this.](http://i304.photobucket.com/albums/nn188/lartkma/latex-example.jpg)

You can make very different forms of place titles and authors, including putting it on the left. This is a example I used in a LaTeX demonstration, with the `calc` package:

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{}{%
   \Huge \thechapter.
}{1cm}{%
   \LARGE \scshape \BeforeSubString{. }{#1}\\
   \makebox[\textwidth - (1cm + \widthof{\Huge \thechapter.})][r]{\Large \itshape \BehindSubString{. }{#1}}%
}
```

About the table of contents, you can ignore it putting the title without the author in the `\chapter` optional argument, or modify it with `titletoc`.

And there are infinite possibilities of writing multi-information titles with these two packages...

PD: Sorry, but for some reason I can't put the CTAN links to the packages.

Answer (score 2):

Grubbing around on [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/) a bit brought me to the [`bits`](http://tug.ctan.org/cgi-bin/ctanPackageInformation.py?id=bits) package which appears to do exactly what you want. From the description:

> A LaTeX package that provides a programmer's interface for a new idea called a “bit”, which is like an environment but has a title, author, and other attributes usually only associated with the document environment.

Be warned that the package claims to be "unsupported".

There is also [`combine`](http://tug.ctan.org/cgi-bin/ctanPackageInformation.py?id=bits):

> The combine class lets you bundle individual documents into a single document, such as when preparing a conference proceedings. The auxiliary combinet package puts the titles and authors from  `\maketitle`  commands into the main document's Table of Contents. The package cooperates with the abstract  and titling  packages.

and there may be others, but as you say, it is not easy to search for.